# In ALM 12.5 My audit Log table only holds 4 weeks of "bug" changes. Is there a purge setting or Size criteria I can change

Tags: data

The Audit log is on a rolling 4-week cycle. Everyday "**BUG**" update history is purged. Looking for how to extend this or stop this from happening ,so I can manage long tail defects better.